# Raster disappears from ArcGIS Pro after applying symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, layers

I've downloaded open data for soils from ISRIC: https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/41cb0ae9-1604-4807-96e6-0dc8c94c5d22

There is an ArcMap document .mxd which opens perfectly in ArcMap:
[image]

But in Pro I see only "world_1" contours.

Also there is a folder with separate files, raster and two layers:

[image]

When I upload raster in Pro I see normal gray scale raster. But when I try to upload symbology from a layer "Dominant soil class", everything just disappears from map, although in contents it is showed like raster with new symbology.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a workaround save your ArcMap symbolized raster as a layer file and then add the layer to Pro.  It will open ArcMap lyr files but can't save to them, but you can save to the Pro layer version ( lyrx).

Comment: @johns thank you, I'll try